# Azure DTUs for a medium size application

Tags: azure-sql-database, database-performance

I am trying to migrate my ASP (IIS) +SQLServer application from SQL Server Express Edition to Azure SQL database. Currently, we only have one dedicated server with both IIS and SQL express edition on it. The planned setup will be ASP (IIS) on an Azure virtual machine and Azure SQL database.

Per my search on google, it seems SQL server Express Edition has performance issues which are resolved in standard and enterprise edition. The DTU calculator indicates that I should move to 200 DTUs. However, that is based on test run on SQL Express edition setup with IIS on the same dedicated server.

Some more information:

1. The database size is around 5 GB currently including backup files.
2. Total users are around 500.
3. Concurrent usage is limited, say around 30-40 users at a time.
4. Bulk usage happens for report retrieval during a certain time frame only by a limited number of users.

I am skeptical to move to 300DTUs given the low number of total users. I am initially assuming 100 DTUs is good enough but looking for some advice on someone who has dealt with this before.

Comment: Hi, can you please give me your thoughts about starting with 200 dtus?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> it seems SQL server Express Edition has performance issues

This is not correct.There are certain limitations like 10GB size,one core CPU and some features are disabled ..

> I am initially assuming 100 DTUs is good enough but looking for some advice on someone who has dealt with this before.

I would go with the advice of DTU calculator,but if you want to go with 100 DTU's,i recommend going with it ,but consistently evaluate performance..

Below query can provide you DTU metrics in your instance and if any one of the metrics is consistently over 90% over  a period of time,i would try to tune that metric and finally upgrade to new tier,if i am not successfull

**DTU query**

```
SELECT start_time, end_time,      
  (SELECT Max(v)      
   FROM (VALUES (avg_cpu_percent), (avg_physical_data_read_percent), (avg_log_write_percent)) AS value(v)) AS [avg_DTU_percent]    
FROM sys.resource_stats   
WHERE database_name = '<your db name>'   
ORDER BY end_time DESC;
```

Comment: Thanks for Sharing. we decided to go for 200 DTUs for now and monitor performance.

Answer (score 0):

Database size and number of users isn't a solid way to estimate DTU usage. A poorly indexed database with a handful of users can consume ridiculous amounts of DTUs. A well-tuned database with lively traffic can consume a comparatively small number of DTUs. At one of my clients, we have a database that handles several million CRUD ops per day over 3,000+ users that rarely breaks 40DTUs.

That being said, don't agonize over your DTU settings. It is REALLY easy to monitor and change. You can scale up or scale down without interrupting service. I'd make a best guess, over-allocate slightly, then move your allocated DTUs up or down based on what you see.

Answer (score 0):

-- Run the following select on the Azure Database you are using

```
SELECT     
  max (avg_cpu_percent),max(avg_data_io_percent),
   max (avg_log_write_percent)  
FROM sys.resource_stats   
WHERE database_name = 'Database_Name'
```